# Can't append series to dataframe in some case

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a newbie pandas user and upsetting for some trouble.

Here's the case.
This is the initial dataframe.

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
  importance interval last_read                last_update    name trigger
0          2      NaN       NaN  2017-12-09 00:00:00+09:00  foobar     NaN
```

And this is the record to append.

```
In [10]: record = df.iloc[0].copy()
```

No error when appending this record.

```
In [11]: df.append(record)
Out[11]: 
  importance interval last_read                last_update    name trigger
0          2      NaN       NaN  2017-12-09 00:00:00+09:00  foobar     NaN
0          2      NaN       NaN  2017-12-09 00:00:00+09:00  foobar     NaN
```

Change a NaN value of record to int and append it, and no error occurs.

```
In [12]: record['interval'] = 1

In [13]: df.append(record)
Out[13]: 
  importance interval last_read                last_update    name trigger
0          2      NaN       NaN  2017-12-09 00:00:00+09:00  foobar     NaN
0          2        1       NaN  2017-12-09 00:00:00+09:00  foobar     NaN
```

Then change another NaN value of record to pd.Timestamp and append.
This occurs an error.

```
In [10]: record
Out[10]: 
importance                             2
interval                             NaN
last_read                            NaN
last_update    2017-12-09 00:00:00+09:00
name                              foobar
trigger                              NaN
Name: 0, dtype: object

In [11]: record['trigger'] = record['last_update']

In [12]: record
Out[12]: 
importance                             2
interval                             NaN
last_read                            NaN
last_update    2017-12-09 00:00:00+09:00
name                              foobar
trigger        2017-12-09 00:00:00+09:00
Name: 0, dtype: object

In [13]: df.append(record)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-7c027f1cbb54> in <module>()
----> 1 df.append(record)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in append(self, other, ignore_index, verify_integrity)
   4545             to_concat = [self, other]
   4546         return concat(to_concat, ignore_index=ignore_index,
-> 4547                       verify_integrity=verify_integrity)
   4548 
   4549     def join(self, other, on=None, how='left', lsuffix='', rsuffix='',

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, copy)
    205                        verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
    206                        copy=copy)
--> 207     return op.get_result()
    208 
    209 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in get_result(self)
    405             new_data = concatenate_block_managers(
    406                 mgrs_indexers, self.new_axes, concat_axis=self.axis,
--> 407                 copy=self.copy)
    408             if not self.copy:
    409                 new_data._consolidate_inplace()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in concatenate_block_managers(mgrs_indexers, axes, concat_axis, copy)
   4830     blocks = [make_block(
   4831         concatenate_join_units(join_units, concat_axis, copy=copy),
-> 4832         placement=placement) for placement, join_units in concat_plan]
   4833 
   4834     return BlockManager(blocks, axes)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   4830     blocks = [make_block(
   4831         concatenate_join_units(join_units, concat_axis, copy=copy),
-> 4832         placement=placement) for placement, join_units in concat_plan]
   4833 
   4834     return BlockManager(blocks, axes)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in concatenate_join_units(join_units, concat_axis, copy)
   4937     to_concat = [ju.get_reindexed_values(empty_dtype=empty_dtype,
   4938                                          upcasted_na=upcasted_na)
-> 4939                  for ju in join_units]
   4940 
   4941     if len(to_concat) == 1:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   4937     to_concat = [ju.get_reindexed_values(empty_dtype=empty_dtype,
   4938                                          upcasted_na=upcasted_na)
-> 4939                  for ju in join_units]
   4940 
   4941     if len(to_concat) == 1:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get_reindexed_values(self, empty_dtype, upcasted_na)
   5210                     pass
   5211                 else:
-> 5212                     missing_arr = np.empty(self.shape, dtype=empty_dtype)
   5213                     missing_arr.fill(fill_value)
   5214                     return missing_arr

TypeError: data type not understood
```

My pandas version is 0.20.3
Could you give me some advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug.
See the link below.

[Github Issues #16044](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16044)

Answer (score 0):

You can try pd.to_datetime instead of timestamp and try

Comment: Thank you for your replay and I'm sorry for my bad code example.  As I understand, you advised me to use pd.to_datetime function to successfully make timestamp. However, timestamp has successfully generated in this case. (just copied from other cell's timestamp value)